# Insert json string into SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: c#, .net, json, sql-server-2008

I have a json string like

```
{"identifier":7,"name":"xyz"}
```

Here *identifier* and *name* are column names. I am passing the table name separately which can vary along with column names.

I want to convert in into insert query statement.

Right now what I am doing:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var d = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(format);
```

It's making the object of each element with keys and values but I don't have any idea how to loop through it.

Please suggest if I am on the right track or if there is any other approach I can use.

Note: The json structure will be same but string can be longer or shorter than the sample I have mentioned above.

Comment: What is the relation with the database?

Comment: Here *identifier* and *name* are column names. I am passing the table name separately which can vary along with column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json by below example. Once you have values parsed in your object then you can use object directly to your ORM or can create query from stringbuilder.

working sample at https://dotnetfiddle.net/trckde

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str ="{\"identifier\":7,\"name\":\"xyzstr\"}";
        DBModel dbModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DBModel>(str);
        Console.WriteLine(dbModel.identifier);
        Console.WriteLine(dbModel.name);

    }
}

public class DBModel
{
   public int identifier { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Thanx...but the thing is that the json string and the DBModel will be dynamic. Looking for something more generic

Answer (score 0):

For generic solution use JObject, you can traverse key value pair then.

Fiddle update : https://dotnetfiddle.net/trckde

```
var str = "{\"identifier\":7,\"name\":\"xyzstr\"}";
            var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(str);
            foreach (var item in jsonObject)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " + item.Value.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```